# Need query to relate unique parent to child that is not unique but can be made unique with MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Parent table (tblLog) has three fields
UserID
Time
Action

Child Table (tblRole) has three fields
UserID
Role
TransDate

I want the query to give me the three fields from tblLog and the Role information from tblRole for each UserID. The problem is that UserID in tblRole is not unique because the table contains historical roles. So what I need to do it only include the UserID and Role for the Max of the TransDate. My understanding is that this is straight forward but I don't know how to do it. Here is the sql that I am trying to fix:

```
SELECT L.[ID]
      ,L.[UserID]
      ,L.[Time]
      ,L.[Action]
      ,R.Role
  FROM [TEST111].[dbo].[tblLog] as L
  Join [TEST111].[dbo].[tblRole] as R
  On  L.[UserID] = R.[UserID]
```

Here is sample data from tblRole*:

```html
ID UserID Role TransDate
1 U001 Super 1/1/2015
2 U001 Super 2/15/2015
3 U001 Mgr 3/7/2015
4 U002 Line 2/10/2015
5 U002 Super 5/4/2015
6 U004 Mgr 4/4/2015
7 U005 Super 1/15/2015
```

*I had previously said that this was sample date from tblLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `ROW_NUMBER` over the `TransDate` for each `UserId`:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  L.[ID],
            L.[UserID],
            L.[Time],
            L.[Action],
            R.[Role],
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By [L].[UserId] Order By [R].[TransDate] Desc) Row_Number
    From    [TEST111].[dbo].[tblLog]    as L
    Join    [TEST111].[dbo].[tblRole]   as R    On  L.[UserID] = R.[UserID]
)
Select  [Id], [UserId], [Time], [Action], [Role]
From    Cte
Where   [Row_Number] = 1
```

This query will pull the most recent transaction information for each `UserId`.

Comment: This looks very promising. Thank you I will try it out!

Comment: Awesome, this does exactly what I need. I need to connect to another table with a simple join so if I can't get that to work I will ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY` the fields that you are determining the value for, then add the `MAX` aggregate for the value you're analyzing.

```
SELECT 
    L.[UserID]
    R.[Role],
    MAX(L.[TransDate]) AS [MaxDate]
FROM [TEST111].[dbo].[tblLog] L
    INNER JOIN [TEST111].[dbo].[tblRole] R
        ON L.[UserID] = R.[UserID]
GROUP BY
    L.[UserID]
    R.[Role]
```

Comment: I don't think the group by will work. I edited the question to include sample data from tblRole. I do not know why but some User and Role combos appear more then once. **UGH - ignore this comment, I just re-read and I understand!**