# Joining three tables, one join uses cte, other join is normal. How do i join this third table to my existing query which uses cte?

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

The data is simple. *tblLog* is a log with UserID, Time, and Action. *tblRole* has UserID and Role and a Date field. *tblActionDesc* has Action and ActionDesc (description). I want the query to give me the information in *tblLog* but also include the Role from *tblRole* (for each UserID) and the ActionDesc from *tblActionDesc* (for each Action).

The first problem I had was that the data in *tblRole* was not unique. It contained many roles per user but it also had a date field. I figured out how to get a unique UserID by utilizing a cte. (HT @Siyual)

[image]

How can I join *tblActionDesc* to the results of this cte?

This is the cte:

```html
;With Cte As
(
    Select  L.[ID],
            L.[UserID],
            L.[Time],
            L.[Action],
            R.[Role],
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By [L].[UserId] Order By [R].[TransDate] Desc) Row_Number
    From    [TEST111].[dbo].[tblLog]    as L
    Join    [TEST111].[dbo].[tblRole]   as R    On  L.[UserID] = R.[UserID]
)
Select  [Id], [UserId], [Time], [Action], [Role]
From    Cte
Where   [Row_Number] = 1
```

This is the code that would work if I did not have the "many" problem in *tblRole*

```html
SELECT L.[ID]
      ,L.[UserID]
      ,L.[Time]
      ,L.[Action]
      ,R.Role
      ,A.ActionDesc
  FROM [TEST111].[dbo].[tblLog] as L
  Join [TEST111].[dbo].[tblRole] as R
  On  L.[UserID] = R.[UserID]
  Join [TEST111].[dbo].[tblActionDesc] as A
  On  L.[Action] = A.[Action]
```

I think that's all the information I need for the question. Here is the question that gave me the cte: [Need query to relate unique parent to child that is not unique but can be made unique with MAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348257/need-query-to-relate-unique-parent-to-child-that-is-not-unique-but-can-be-made-u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
 with cte1 as (
    -- Get the most recent TransDate for each UserID.
    select UserID, max(TransDate) as max_trans_date
    from tblRole
    group by UserID
),
cte2 as (
    -- Now that we know the most recent record for each user, 
    -- get the actual data (i.e. "Role") for each UserID.
    select r.UserID, r.[Role]
    from tblRole as r
        inner join cte1 on r.UserID = cte1.UserID and r.TransDate = cte1.max_trans_date
)
select l.ID, l.UserID, l.[Time], l.[Action], cte2.[Role], ad.ActionDesc
from tblLog as l
    left join cte2 on l.UserID = cte2.UserID
    left join tblActionDesc as ad on l.[Action] = ad.[Action]
```

Edit: Updated for question in comments.

Comment: Yes, this works. One question - you use all inner joins. In fact I have UserIDs in tblLog that do not have a matching record in tblRole. How can I change your query to give me all records in tblLog, not only those with a match in tblRole? And actually I want all records from tblLog even if they don't have a match in tblActionDesc

Answer (score 1):

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  ID, UserID, Role, TransDate,
            Row_Number OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY TransDate DESC) Row_Number
    From    tblRole
)

SELECT L.[ID]
      ,L.[UserID]
      ,L.[Time]
      ,L.[Action]
      ,R.Role
      ,A.ActionDesc
  FROM [TEST111].[dbo].[tblLog] as L
  Join cte as R
  On  L.[UserID] = R.[UserID]
  Join [TEST111].[dbo].[tblActionDesc] as A
  On  L.[Action] = A.[Action]
  WHERE R.Row_Number = 1
```

Comment: It seems like that is applying the *Row_Number = 1* criteria to the tblLog results. I cannot really tell what is off, but the results are only showing one record for each user from tblLog (but tblLog contains more than one records per user).

Comment: Is that what you wanted though? `tblLog` has more than 1 record per user but you only wanted the one that has the last `TransDate`

Comment: For example - User1 has three actions in *TblLog*. I want all three actions in the result. User1 has two roles in *tblRole* like: Supervisor 1/1/15 and Manager 3/15/2015. So I want **Manager** to appear on each of the three log records in the result.

Comment: Then your CTE was incorrect. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Yes! that did it. One question which really shows my ignorace - how do I change this to return all records from tblLog, even those that do not have a match in tblRole?